# Why getRequest() throws NullPointerException in Rest-service?

Tags: java, spring

I have spring-rest service and method importPayments:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/importPayments"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, List<Payment>> importPayments() throws IOException {
        ImportPaymentsOutcome outcome = paymentService.importPayments(getRequest().getInputStream());
        ImportPaymentsOutcomeModel importPaymentsOutcome = new ImportPaymentsOutcomeModel(outcome);
```

How to get request and extract from it inputStream?
When I try to call getRequest() - there is NullPointerException.

I tried to use importPayments(HttpServletRequest request) imput param, but I need to change old rests with params on new with empty method params.

Comment: You cannot achieve this by an empty method params, and why do you want that?

Comment: this class is derrived from ... ? I think annotated REST services should NOT derivve nothing complicated, so `getRequest()` should be undefined. These are magaed by container

Comment: i agree with @aydinugur. Why you need to get rid of params?

Comment: ....  read 5th chapter http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping. And Your class should not override servlet, filter or whatever You try. This path is wrong